# Dynamic CSV load in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv

Ok so I have been searching the internet for a solution but have not yet come up with anything yet

What I have is a CSV - this CSV could have any number of unknown columns

e.g.

```
Col 1, Col 2, Col 3
```

I have used `BULK INSERT #temp FROM ...` to insert from a CSV but this relies on me having a table before hand to load into - This is where the problem arises - I don’t know my table structure before loading the CSV

Is there a way to dynamically create the table, based on the CSV, on the fly to load the data into?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Thanks for the edit Marc_S - sorry about the formatting

Comment: I was thinking i could make a table with one column as ntext and load the csv lines into it - then parse this using the database, There must be a better way though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV parsing is non-trivial (taking into account text qualifiers, values that contain linebreaks, qualifier escape mechanisms, etc). There are several .Net libraries out there that do all this stuff for you (eg http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx), so I would think it would be easier to use a different technology, eg powershell, or SQL CLR, to make use of an existing library - rather that trying to roll your own CSV parser in T-SQL...

Huh, just found this nice and simple solution on an old forum post (http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?t=47966):

```
select * 
from OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; DefaultDir=D:\;',
'select * from test1.csv')
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work on recent windows versions where the text driver isn't installed by default...

Comment: Is there another way to read a CSV from MSSQL - as OpenRowset requires a grant permission

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same tasks many many times. What I ended up doing is writing a simple c# script for the load. I can admit, each time I had to change the script a little bit, because each time the requirements were different, the CSV file had specific peculiarities, etc. This means that my code most likely won't work for you straight away, but I hope that it can help you a lot.

The main C# file is program.cs. Here is its source:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

namespace CsvToSql
{
    class Program
    {
        static string server = @"localhost";
        static string database = @"test";
        static bool hasHeaders = false;
        static string fieldLength = "max";

        static string fieldPattern = "[%fieldName%] [nvarchar](%fieldLength%) NULL,\n";        
        static string createTablePattern = 
@"
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[%tableName%]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[%tableName%]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[%tableName%](
%fields%
) ON [PRIMARY]
";
        static string commandScriptPattern = 
@"sqlcmd -S %server% -E -d %database% -i %tableScriptName% 
bcp %database%.dbo.%tableName% in %headrelsessFileName%  -c -t^^ -r \n -T -S %server%
";
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            server = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["server"] ?? server;
            database = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["database"] ?? database;
            hasHeaders = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["hasHeaders"] == "true";
            fieldLength = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["fieldLength"] ?? fieldLength;

            string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.csv");
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", fileName);
                Process(fileName);
            }
            WriteExecuteAllFile(fileNames);
            WriteCleanUpFile(fileNames);
        }

        private static void Process(string fileName)
        {
            string[] fieldNames = ReadHeaders(fileName);
            ProduceTableScript(fileName, fieldNames);
            ProduceCommandScript(fileName);
        }

        private static void WriteExecuteAllFile(string[] fileNames)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                sb.Append("call ");
                sb.AppendLine(GetCommandScriptName(fileName));
            }
            SaveStringToFile(sb.ToString(), "_all.cmd");
        }

        private static void WriteCleanUpFile(string[] fileNames)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                sb.Append("del ");
                sb.AppendLine(GetCommandScriptName(fileName));
                sb.Append("del ");
                sb.AppendLine(GetHeaderlessFileName(fileName));
                sb.Append("del ");
                sb.AppendLine(GetTableScriptName(fileName));
            }
            sb.AppendLine("del _all.cmd");
            sb.AppendLine("del _cleanup.cmd");
            SaveStringToFile(sb.ToString(), "_cleanup.cmd");
        }

        private static string[] ReadHeaders(string fileName)
        {            
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                if (hasHeaders)
                {
                        string[] result = ParseQutationLineToList(sr.ReadLine());
                        ProduceHeaderlessFile(sr, fs.Name);
                        return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    string s = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] fields = ParseQutationLineToList(s);
                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    sr.DiscardBufferedData();
                    string[] result = new string[fields.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                    {
                        result[i] = "F" + (i + 1).ToString();
                    }
                    ProduceHeaderlessFile(sr, fs.Name);
                    return result;
                }
           }
        }

        private static void ProduceTableScript(string fileName, string[] fieldNames)
        {
            string tableName = GetTableName(fileName);
            string fields = fieldNames.Aggregate("", (s, i) => s + fieldPattern.Replace("%fieldName%", i).Replace("%fieldLength%", fieldLength));
            string table = createTablePattern.Replace("%fields%", fields).Replace("%tableName%", tableName);
            SaveStringToFile(table, GetTableScriptName(fileName));
        }


        private static void ProduceCommandScript(string fileName)
        {
            string content = commandScriptPattern;
            content = content.Replace("%server%", server);
            content = content.Replace("%database%", database);
            content = content.Replace("%tableName%", GetTableName(fileName));
            content = content.Replace("%tableScriptName%", GetTableScriptName(fileName));
            content = content.Replace("%headrelsessFileName%", GetHeaderlessFileName(fileName));
            SaveStringToFile(content, GetCommandScriptName(fileName));
        }

        private static void ProduceHeaderlessFile(StreamReader sr, string basefileName)
        {
            string headerlessFileName = GetHeaderlessFileName(basefileName);
            if (File.Exists(headerlessFileName))
            {
                return;
            }

            int counter = 0;

            using(FileStream fs = File.Open(headerlessFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                while(!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine().Replace("\"", ""));
                    sw.WriteLine(ParseLine(sr.ReadLine()));
                    counter++;
                }
                sw.Flush();
                fs.Flush();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Written {0} records to {1}", counter, headerlessFileName);
        }

        private static string ParseLine(string s)
        {
            if (s.TrimStart(' ', '\t').StartsWith("\""))
            {
                return ParseQutationLine(s);
            }

            return s.Replace(',', '^');
        }

        // Some tables has the default field terminator (comma) inside them
        // this is why we have to parse
        private static string ParseQutationLine(string s)
        {

            string[] fields = ParseQutationLineToList(s);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                sb.Append(field.Trim('"'));
                sb.Append('^');
                if (field.IndexOf('^') >= 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("String contains separator character. " + s);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
        }

        private static string[] ParseQutationLineToList(string s)
        {
            JouniHeikniemi.Tools.Strings.CsvReader cr = new JouniHeikniemi.Tools.Strings.CsvReader();
            ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
            cr.ParseCsvFields(result, s);
            return (string[])result.ToArray(typeof(string));
        }

        private static void SaveStringToFile(string s, string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.Write(s);
                sw.Flush();
                fs.Flush();
            }
        }

        private static string GetTableName(string fileName)
        {
            return "_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Replace('.', '_');
        }

        private static string GetHeaderlessFileName(string fileName)
        {
            return Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "inp");
        }

        private static string GetTableScriptName(string fileName)
        {
            return Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "tbl");
        }

        private static string GetCommandScriptName(string fileName)
        {
            return Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "cmd");
        }
    }
}
```

This file use a library that [I found in internet](http://www.heikniemi.fi/jhlib/) for parsing CSV file. Note, that I saw valid CSV files, that this library failed to parse. The text for CsvReader.cs file follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace JouniHeikniemi.Tools.Strings {

  /// <summary>
  /// A data-reader style interface for reading Csv (and otherwise-char-separated) files.
  /// </summary>
  public class CsvReader : IDisposable {

    #region Private variables

    private Stream stream;
    private StreamReader reader;
    private char separator;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public CsvReader() { separator = ','; }

      /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Csv reader for the given stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The stream to read the CSV from.</param>
    public CsvReader(Stream s) : this(s, null, ',') { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new reader for the given stream and separator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The stream to read the separator from.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The field separator character</param>
    public CsvReader(Stream s, char separator) : this(s, null, separator) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Csv reader for the given stream and encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The stream to read the CSV from.</param>
    /// <param name="enc">The encoding used.</param>
    public CsvReader(Stream s, Encoding enc) : this(s, enc, ',') { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new reader for the given stream, encoding and separator character.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The stream to read the data from.</param>
    /// <param name="enc">The encoding used.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The separator character between the fields</param>
    public CsvReader(Stream s, Encoding enc, char separator) {

      this.separator = separator;
      this.stream = s;
      if (!s.CanRead) {
        throw new CsvReaderException("Could not read the given data stream!");
      }
      reader = (enc != null) ? new StreamReader(s, enc) : new StreamReader(s);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Csv reader for the given text file path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The name of the file to be read.</param>
    public CsvReader(string filename) : this(filename, null, ',') { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new reader for the given text file path and separator character.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The name of the file to be read.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The field separator character</param>
    public CsvReader(string filename, char separator) : this(filename, null, separator) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Csv reader for the given text file path and encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The name of the file to be read.</param>
    /// <param name="enc">The encoding used.</param>
    public CsvReader(string filename, Encoding enc) 
      : this(filename, enc, ',') { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new reader for the given text file path, encoding and field separator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The name of the file to be read.</param>
    /// <param name="enc">The encoding used.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The field separator character.</param>
    public CsvReader(string filename, Encoding enc, char separator) 
      : this(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open), enc, separator) { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The separator character for the fields. Comma for normal CSV.
    /// </summary>
    public char Separator {
      get { return separator; }
      set { separator = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Parsing

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the fields for the next row of data (or null if at eof)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string array of fields or null if at the end of file.</returns>
    public string[] GetCsvLine() {

      string data = reader.ReadLine();
      if (data == null) return null;
      if (data.Length == 0) return new string[0];

      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

      ParseCsvFields(result, data);

      return (string[])result.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }

    // Parses the fields and pushes the fields into the result arraylist
    public void ParseCsvFields(ArrayList result, string data) {

      int pos = -1;
      while (pos < data.Length)
        result.Add(ParseCsvField(data, ref pos));
    }

    // Parses the field at the given position of the data, modified pos to match
    // the first unparsed position and returns the parsed field
    private string ParseCsvField(string data, ref int startSeparatorPosition) {

      if (startSeparatorPosition == data.Length-1) {
        startSeparatorPosition++;
        // The last field is empty
        return "";
      }

      int fromPos = startSeparatorPosition + 1;

      // Determine if this is a quoted field
      if (data[fromPos] == '"') {
        // If we're at the end of the string, let's consider this a field that
        // only contains the quote
        if (fromPos == data.Length-1) {
          fromPos++;
          return "\"";
        }

        // Otherwise, return a string of appropriate length with double quotes collapsed
        // Note that FSQ returns data.Length if no single quote was found
        int nextSingleQuote = FindSingleQuote(data, fromPos+1);
        startSeparatorPosition = nextSingleQuote+1;
        return data.Substring(fromPos+1, nextSingleQuote-fromPos-1).Replace("\"\"", "\"");
      }

      // The field ends in the next separator or EOL
      int nextSeparator = data.IndexOf(separator, fromPos);
      if (nextSeparator == -1) {
        startSeparatorPosition = data.Length;
        return data.Substring(fromPos);
      }
      else {
        startSeparatorPosition = nextSeparator;
        return data.Substring(fromPos, nextSeparator - fromPos);
      }
    }

    // Returns the index of the next single quote mark in the string 
    // (starting from startFrom)
    private static int FindSingleQuote(string data, int startFrom) {

      int i = startFrom-1;
      while (++i < data.Length)
        if (data[i] == '"') {
          // If this is a double quote, bypass the chars
          if (i < data.Length-1 && data[i+1] == '"') {
            i++;
            continue;
          }
          else
            return i;
        }
      // If no quote found, return the end value of i (data.Length)
      return i;
    }

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the reader. The underlying stream is closed.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose() {
      // Closing the reader closes the underlying stream, too
      if (reader != null) reader.Close();
      else if (stream != null)
        stream.Close(); // In case we failed before the reader was constructed
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Exception class for CsvReader exceptions.
  /// </summary>
  [Serializable]
  public class CsvReaderException : ApplicationException { 

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new CsvReaderException.
    /// </summary>
    public CsvReaderException() : this("The CSV Reader encountered an error.") { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new exception with the given message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The exception message.</param>
    public CsvReaderException(string message) : base(message) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new exception with the given message and the inner exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The exception message.</param>
    /// <param name="inner">Inner exception that caused this issue.</param>
    public CsvReaderException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new exception with the given serialization information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    protected CsvReaderException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, 
                                 System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) 
      : base(info, context) { }

  }

}
```

I also have a config file CsvToSql.exe.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="server" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="database" value="test"/>
    <!-- If your csv files have header, set this to true to generate field names from headers-->
    <!-- Otherwise set it to false to generate names F1, F2, F3, etc.-->
    <add key="hasHeaders" value="false"/>
    <!-- This is the lenght of nvarchar field created can be a number or 'max'-->
    <add key="fieldLength" value="500"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And a script that compiles the whole lot build.cmd:

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /out:CsvToSql.exe Program.cs CsvReader.cs
```

This is how I use it:

- Run build.cmd to compile CsvToSql.exe
- Edit CsvToSql.exe.config to fit your case
- Put csv files in the same folder the executable and the config file
- Run CsvToSql.exe
- The executable does not connect to the database. Instead it produces a number of files:
  *.tbl files are table definitions, *.inp files are input files for bcp command line utility, *.cmd files are files that run table creation scripts and bcp command line utility. _all.cmd that runs *.cmd for all tables and _cleanup.cmd that deletes all the files that CsvToSql.exe generates
- Run _all.cmd file
- Go to your SQL and look at what has been produced. Make changes to the script and / or config, rinse and repeat

There are a lot of assumtions that this script makes, and also a lot of stuff that is hardcoded. This is what I usaully quickly change each new time I need to load a set of CSV into SQL.

Good luck and if you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.
The script requires .NET 3.5
If there is no extra-special about data I'm loading, I'm usually up and running with this script in 15 minutes. If there are troubles, twicking might take longer.

Comment: Nice code, I may borrow part of it for a project I'm working on now!

Comment: Very nice code and I may use this in the future - thank you however im looking for a database only solution